# When mistake?Undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Learn the rails on the book Michael Hartl and listing 7.5 when i create new user, my browser show me error.

> ```
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
> ```

This is my users controller

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def show
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

and this my show.html

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
```

Comment: user_params have a name param?

Comment: You see how it says *for nil:NilClass*; that means you've got a null object. In other words, there is no `User` object with that id (whatever `params[:id]` is). Check the database, manually verify there are rows in the `users` table, and make sure there is one with the id you're looking for. If not, something wrong happened along the way (you'll have to look a little deeper).

Comment: http://cs618225.vk.me/v618225007/1adbe/9FRcqdUedgc.jpg

Comment: @PaulRichter the ActiveRecord's method `.find` raises an error (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) if no record is found for the id passed as argument. This is not happening since the error is not ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound but a nil pointer exception.

Comment: Have you tried to move your show action outside of the private methods? I am not sure but I think that Rails can't access a Controller's private method in this case

Comment: :D I'm sorry, was not thinking.stupid) thank you!

Comment: @MrYoshiji You're absolutely right, I completely forgot about that. My mistake.